# Differ PhpMailer in AngularJS foreach

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, foreach, phpmailer

I have problems :

My code for emailing is working, but I don't think its the right way to do so. Is it possible to use the $http service inside an AngularJS foreach loop? Will it overheat the process, if each loop is destined to PhpMailer to send one mail each time? Should I use the $q service? The code works to send a low amount of emails but will it overheat the php script if more emails are sent?

**AngularJS code**

```
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.intervenants,function(data){
        var x = angular.copy($scope.formData);
        x.destinataire = data.email;
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'contact-form.php',
            data    : $.param(x),  //param method from jQuery
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-success';
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-danger';
            }
        });
   });
}
```

**PhpMail code**

```
//check if any of the inputs are empty
if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
} 

//create an instance of PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.orange.fr"; 

$mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['destinataire']); //recipient 
$mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
$mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
    $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: send them all in one request and let php handle throttling if needed. How many are you trying to send?

Comment: Yep, don't try to do this from Angular, it's just the wrong place. Get angular to pass the whole array to PHP and let it deal with the send - look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMiler for guidance.

Comment: Yes i thought about doing a loop into the php back end ? Well, it could be 200 emails for 200 differents persons ...